# Considering weights right of the embeddings layer aren't used in Doc2Vec/Word2Vec, is the informative capacity of the embeddings not strongly reduced?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, word2vec, doc2vec

In an extreme (and probably impossible) example, could you not end up with all the power for the prediction being contained in the weights to the right of the embeddings layer?...and thus the matrix to the left of the embeddings(and therefore embeddings) would be useless?

Answer (score 1):

The word2vec architecture is nicely visualized here: [image: https://israelg99.github.io/images/2017-03-23-Word2Vec-Explained/skip_gram_net_arch.png]

With regards to your question, we have the "left" embeddings are the weights, $W_l$, of the embedding layer itself (one-hot index to vector hidden layer), and the "right" embeddings, $W_r$, which transform these embeddings to predict for a certain class (depending on the pretraining objective).

If $x$ is the input token and $\sigma$ a softmax activation, then our prediction will look like:

$$\max \mathrm{\sigma} (W_r (W_lx) + b)$$

When you mention power, I assume it's predictive ability. The thought process you're following seems like

> If the accuracy of the prediction is coming from $W_r$, doesn't that
> mean $W_l$ will be useless?

But notice that in our formula above for the prediction, the inputs to $W_r$ are the weights in $W_l$!

**If $W_r$ successively predicts, then $W_l$ must have structure (in the embedding weights) that is predictable, i.e. one can train predictions (like downstream tasks in NLP) on these embeddings.**